# Can threads share common data elements when all belong to the same class?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I have a `class A` that has a dictionary with other nested dictionaries.

```
class A():
   def __init__(self,_dict):
      self._dict = _dict
 

   def _start_daemon_threads(self):
      #iterate the dictionary and start a daemon thread for each key in the dictionary
```

Each thread is listening to a streaming source of data that is related to each dictionary's key.

The function that is targeted in the `_start_daemon_threads` function access and modifies the `self._dict` dictionary as needed (or at least, this is desired).

So, my question is, when starting each daemon thread, each thread do actually read and modify the `self._dict` dictionary or each threads reads and modify a copy of it? The dictionary is not an argument of the targeted function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they should modify that `dictionary` it will be modified because dictionaries in python are treated by reference and that dictionary is part of the `instance` of `A`, you just need to take care of possible `deadlocks` so the code can execute correctly

```py
a = A()
a._start_daemon_threads
```

The snippet above should run correctly (depends on your code of course) and modify the dictionary as needed